# How can i ignore media queries in css file?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a web project that use css file with media queries.
one of the page is using the same css file but i don't want it to use the media queries on this css file. how can i ignore them?

Comment: Remove it or use `/* */` to comment it... What do you exactly mean with 'ignore them'.

Comment: I think you want to have some CSS that says: "Now ignore this one". I'm not aware of such a thing.

Comment: @HerrSerker we can **override** in CSS which will cause the CSS to ignore the overriden styles

Comment: @Danield Of course, But this is not ignore. You have to know the CSS selectors and rules inside the media-queries to override them. But this may be tedious and is not future save, as there may be added styles to the media query.

Comment: @HerrSerker - an easier way to override would be to move the media queries to the top of the css file - I updated my post

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ignore the media queries (and don't want to just comment them out -for some reason) then an easy way to do this is to **move all the media queries to the top** of the CSS file.

This way, the same classes will override the styles in the media queries. eg:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) { /* or whatever the media query is */
  .class {
    /*styles here */
  }
}
.class {
/*styles here */
}
```

Alternatively, (if the above method isn't possible), you could
 **add specificity** to the selectors (which the media queries select) eg:

```
.class.class {   /* <-- added specificity */
  /*styles here */
}

@media (max-width: 600px) { /* or whatever the media query is */
  .class {
    /*styles here */
  }
}
```

Now the .class selecter will ***override*** the media query and the media query will be ignored.

Comment: Using the same class twice in the selector for adding specificity. Nice trick

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to comment the media queries because other pages are using them. also move the media queries to the top won't help for the other pages.

Comment: for the page that you **don't** want the media queries: say the container element in that page had class 'page1', then add specificity to the selectors which the media queries select in the form of  `.page1 .class { /* style here */ }`

Answer (score 0):

You can negate your selectors with the :not() attribute for the selectors you don't want the query style applied to in css like this...

```
.page{ /* Styles that apply to all ".page" elements before media query */ }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Defines styles for elements with the "page" class */
  .page:not(:first)     { 
      /* Excludes first matching element with "page" class */ }
  .page:not(.firstpage) { 
      /* Excludes elements with the "firstpage" class */ }
  .page:not(#firstpage) { 
      /* Excludes element with id="firstpage" */ }
```

Then if you want to do something with only the excluded page when the media query is activated, you can add...

```
   .page(:first) { } 
     /* or */
   .firstpage    { } 
     /* or */
   #firstpage    { }
}
```