# Disable media queries of third party CSS file

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I am importing a css file from a third party (it means I cannot edit the css file). And this css file is using media queries which I want to disable them in my page.

A possible solution is to overwrite all of media queries in a new css file which requires to override thousands of css selectors in my case.

I found this JS solution which works fine in mobile browsers but it does not work in desktop browsers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=1440');
});
```

Solutions in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28040836/3328979) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15388967/3328979) are not useful because they require to change the css file.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? Ideally there'd be some way to replicate the viewport meta on desktop user agents.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the whole file first

```
$('link[href~="test.css"]').remove();
```

and dynamically add the style from your domain without the media query.

Comment: I need the css file! I have added it myself. I want to disable its media queries as the site should not be responsive.